# Google API's - Validity of server key and browser key?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube Data API.I would like to know about the validity of both browser key and server keys ? I need these keys to run my application without any user authentication.
So I need to confirm which key works well for me .

I am running scripts to get results from YouTube search API and my scripts are uploaded and executed using cron jobs.
I could not find a good article or question on this.

I would greatly appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the read-only endpoints of the data API (such as searching, listing, etc.), then you'll be able to do what you want with a **browser key**. Your scripts will just include it as a URL parameter (ie. ...&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE). If you ever want to do anything more than the read-only tasks (such as uploading videos, deleting info, etc.), you'll have to use oAuth.

Comment: Can u explain whats server key then?

Comment: AFAIK the only major difference is that you control access of the browser key by setting different allowed domains, while the server key has to have white listed IP addresses. Obviously this means you won't want to use a server key in a client side app, but the browser key can be used in a server side app. For analytics purposes you may wish to separate them, though. There may be other differences I'm not aware of.